# AJAX get returned but doesnt show the value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been working on a simple stuff for couple of days but I can't get to a solution.
I have a table:

First column its the article code, second the description, and the other columns are the stores where the article are and the ammount of them.
Everytime i go over a quantity (the number) I'll make an ajax request to a PHP script. 
I won't even explain what the script will do because I just forced to give me back a default value, just for debugging.

When I'll go over that cell I'll show up a tooltip with the image of the product (i forced the image too for debug) and under the image a text (the forced ajax response).
My problem is that sometimes it show up the tooltip with the forced image but not the forced ajax response. it gives me an empty responce.

At the beggining was everything ok, then it started to do on a couple of specific cells, then I refreshed and I started on other cells.
I can't understand this behavior (added the table as an example if you want to try, and filled with console log to check that everything works).

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <!-- dataType: "json", -->
        <title></title>
        <style>



    img{border:none;}
    #tooltip{
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background:#333;
        padding:5px;
        display:none;
        color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){

            $("td").mouseover(function(){

          var magazzino = ""; //store
          var codice = "";   //code
          var quantita = 0;   //quantity

          var row = $(this).parent().index('tr');
          var col = ($(this).index('tr:eq('+row+') td'));

          var cord = $(this).offset();


          console.log("row: "+row+" col: "+col);
          console.log("left: "+cord.left+ " top: "+cord.top);

                quantita = $.trim($(this).text());
          codice = $.trim($("table > tbody > tr:eq("+row+") > td.cod").text());
          magazzino = $.trim($("table > tbody > tr:first-child > td:eq("+col+")").text());

          console.log("the code is': "+codice+ "the store is': "+magazzino);

          if(quantita > 0){  $.ajax({

                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {magazzino:magazzino , codice:codice},

                    success: function(result){


                       $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'><img src='http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10-blue' alt='ajax' /></br>"+ result +"</p>");                 
                       $("#tooltip")
                                    .css("top",( cord.top + 20) + "px")
                                    .css("left",( cord.left + 20) + "px")
                                    .fadeIn(400);  
                        console.log("it get in here! will it show the result?: "+result);
                    }
                });
          }

            });

        $("td").mouseout(function(){
                $('#tooltip').remove();
        });

    });


        </script>
    </head>
<body>
  <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">Codice_articolo</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">Descrizione</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">GM</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">GR</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">AM</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">DM</td>
      <td class="wrap GD" title="">GD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">bsd555</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">router</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">1</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">4</td>
      <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">alfa456</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">macchina</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">2</td>
      <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">rityui765</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">router</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">1</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">2</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">gefr5444</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">pc</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">2</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">1</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">4</td>
      <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">koiuy</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">frigo</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">1</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">4</td>
       <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left cod" title="">muiui899</td>
      <td class="center desc" title="">cell</td>
      <td class="center GM" title="">1</td>
      <td class="center GR" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center AM" title="">0</td>
      <td class="center DM" title="">1</td>
       <td class="wrap GD" title="">0</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Instead of mouseover, you should use mouseenter event i guess. And i'd use mouseleave event instead of mouseout too. Anyway, doing ajax request following any mouse event looks weird.

Comment: Well i've been asked to do this stuff. When the mouse is over the cell show the product image and that stuff(ive been asked to make it with ajax). what else i could try?
Why mousenter should be better? 
I was doing this with chrome, i tried with firefox and everything works. But i bet it will starts tog et mad soon too.

Comment: mouseenter looks better here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwB7H/  Will limit amount of useless requests in case your TD contains other DOM elements. But i just checked your HTML, in your case this won't change anything i guess

Comment: Funny that i tried mouseenter and started to work again. It just acts random and i cant understand why.
Do you suggest other easier way?

Comment: I really think your server cannot handle as much as requests you are doing. I'd not use this kind of logic in first place, doing a new ajax request each time the user get over a TD.

Comment: It's  what i thought, but i noticed that it doesnt show only with certain td, so was bit strange. 
But im doing this for an other person and (ofc) he cant accept that it kind doesnt work well like this, and pushes me to find a solution.